# Return DateTime.Now in decimals

Tags: c#

How do I change the time from 60 minutes to 100 in an hour?

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
{
      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => LokaleTijdRange.Value = 
      float.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm"), 
      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));
}
```

With this code, I'm getting normal times (but then with "." instead of ":") like `19:12`, `23:20` etc... However, is there a way to make it so that the time will be displayed in decimals of an hour? So that `20:30` gives `20.5`, and `20:45` will give `20.75`? I need this so I can count with times.

Comment: `...so I can count with times` <= This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? What do you mean by "count with times"?

Comment: I’m sure there is a way, by finding the 3 and 4th numbers, dividing them by 100, and joining the decimal onto the time

Comment: sample code: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a432c495-79f8-45d3-becb-79b5acec0ba8/convert-total-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes-in-c-winform?forum=winforms

Comment: I have a circle diagram which represents a clock with different time ranges. The start and end values of those ranges have to be in decimals. I store those range values like this `Application.Current.Properties["voedingrange1_start_value"] = "7.5";` for example. Now I want to make the text that displays the upcoming time bold. See this picture: https://i.gyazo.com/3b56463f16bd2f358efc0bdb349aeb12.jpg In this example the time underneath "Slaap" should be blue and the first time underneath "Voeding" should be bold. Anyway, if the current time is in decimals, I can compare this with the others.

Comment: @Igor Why does it actually matter for what purposes I need to know how to convert something? Why is it downvoted?

Comment: @JipHarthoorn - Often there is a better way of doing something once the whole problem is understood that accomplishes the actual goal that the developer is trying to reach. For example: Maybe your end goal was to be able to sort a listed of DateTime instances based on time, in that case a better answer would be that this could be done with Linq and the TimeOfDay property and no conversion was needed.

Comment: As for downvoting don't assume who downvoted your question (or others) unless the voter leaves feedback stating they did. You have 2 downvotes, those 2 might not even have left a comment on your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For my goal, using the current time and calculate what the upcoming time will be of a list of times, is this a good approach (convert the current date time to `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours` and compare that with for example `Application.Current.Properties["voedingrange1_start_value"] = "7.5";`

Comment: `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` is a [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2) which has several operators / methods / properties that are more useful than a decimal when working with times. You can also parse a TimeSpan for roud trip serialization. So if it were up to me I would use that over the `TotalHours`, chances are it will only make your code easier to implement / read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use just `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours`.

Comment: Exactly, and do `.ToString("F2")` on that, for example, to have just two decimals.

Comment: this answer not good. The orignal asker want a industrial time format. Some old program is still use it, beacuse the mathematic of this time format was more easy,

Comment: Or, `(float)Math.Round(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours, 2)` to avoid back and forth conversion (to string and parse).

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the time in DateTime into decimal value:

```
DateTime originalDT = Date.now();
float timeInDecimals = (float)originalDT.Hour + (float)(originalDT.Minute / 60.0);
```